# How to I retrieve the length in seconds of a <video> element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a `<video>` tag with the id of "liveVideo". How do I retrieve the length of the video in seconds?

Thanks,

David!

Comment: yes, <video> is only supported in HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`media.duration` check the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#offsets-into-the-media-resource

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#liveVideo').attr('duration') // will return the full length of the movie
```